# Problem with importing camelcase module to Python (VSCode terminal)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module

I am trying to import camelcase module to python:

```
from camelcase import CamelCase
txt = 'hello there world'
c = CamelCase()
print(c.hump(txt))
```

I get an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'camelcase'

I tried also:

```
import camelcase
txt = 'hello there world'
c = camelcase.CamelCase()
print(c.hump(txt))
```

Same issue. I have newest version of pip installed:

```
--pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from C:\Users\Eryk Słowiński\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

And for sure I have installed camelcase

```
--pip freeze
appdirs==1.4.3
camelcase==0.2
importlib-metadata==1.5.0
virtualenv==20.0.3
zipp==2.2.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you see `camelcase` in the result of `pip list`

Comment: Yes I also see it in pip list. However I think I've found the source of the problem (I will edit my post). Anyway thanks for your concern

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I have found source of problem, I've installed virtual environment and I guess it was in wrong location. I deleted it and when I use my packages globally it works okay. 
I guess I should take some tutorial how to use env before i mess with it in my terminal :D